# Protect communication between WCF client and service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, encryption

I have a WCF service with one method:

```
[OperationContract]
bool VerifyLicense(string clientId, string license);
```

This is hosted on a public web server. When called from an app deployed on a client Intranet, it checks whether that client has a current license to continue using the app.

However, presumably it would be quite easy to intercept this and just return `true`.

What would be the easiest way to protect against this? Would encryption work? Please provide a code sample because I've never used encryption before. I can't make sense of some of the stuff thrown up by Google... certificates, etc. Is there an easier way?

Comment: By default, **all** communications in WCF is a) encrypted, and b) signed, so you should be on the safe side...

Comment: +1 I didn't know that. If someone records a signed and encrypted 'true' response from the service at one time, couldn't they later spoof the service by sending the same response to a different request? Or does the encryption protect against that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, all communications in WCF is a) encrypted, and b) signed, so you should be on the safe side...  (you can choose to turn this off - but it's on by default)

Resources:

- [Fundamentals of WCF Security](http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/33342/1763/)
- [Practices at a Glance: WCF Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647607.aspx)

and in particular
- [How to: Enable Message Replay Detection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733063.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. So by default, responses older than 5 minutes cannot be replayed?

Comment: @James: that's what I understand, yes - anything with a timestamp older than 5 minutes ago will be discarded by the service and not processed